# AngularJS insert data to to JSON file

Tags: angularjs, json

I have been trying and failing at this all day. I'm quite new to all this. This is a very simple angularJS learning exercise that I can't figure out.

My GET command successfully pulls the JSON data but the POST command in the addItem function is non-responsive. I believe I'm missing the server configuration but I don't know where I would put this.

There are only two files; the app and the json file (list.php); the content of both below. This app is currently running at:

http://pagemakr.com/list/L8/

---

THE APP - index.php:

```
    <script>

            var app = angular.module("myShoppingList", []); 

            app.controller("myCtrlx", function($scope,$http) {

                $http.get("list.php").then(function (response) {
                    $scope.items = response.data.items;
                });

                $scope.addItem = function () {
                    var data = { "item":$scope.itemInput }                    
                    $http.post("list.php", data).then(function (response) {
                            if (response.data)
                            $scope.msg = "Success!";
                    }, function (response) {
                            $scope.msg = "Didn't Work!";
                    });
                }
            });

    </script>


    <div ng-app="myShoppingList" ng-cloak ng-controller="myCtrlx" class="w3-card-2 w3-margin" style="max-width:400px;">

      <header class="w3-container w3-light-grey w3-padding-16"><h3>List</h3></header>

      <ul class="w3-ul">
            <li ng-repeat="x in items" class="w3-padding-16">{{x.item}}<span ng-click="removeItem($index)" style="cursor:pointer;" class="w3-right w3-margin-right">x</span></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="w3-container w3-light-grey w3-padding-16">
          <div class="w3-row w3-margin-top">
              <div class="w3-col s10">
                  <input placeholder="Add items here" ng-model="itemInput" class="w3-input w3-border w3-padding">
              </div>
              <div class="w3-col s2">
                  <button type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="addItem()" class="w3-btn w3-padding w3-green">Add</button>
              </div>
          </div>
          <p class="w3-text-red">{{errortext}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

THE JSON DATABASE - list.php:

```
{
    "items":
    [
    {"item":"peas"},
    {"item":"carrots"},
    {"item":"jam"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: You are suppose to use the Forms to create your div for fetching the info.

Comment: In your post function if you are getting the result message: "Didn't Work!" you might not be returning (via print/echo) any data from list.php

Comment: you cant insert to json file without server side language . If you have code in php file . Please provide it

Comment: My console shows the POST as `status 200 OK` with the `response.data` identical to the original list. Data in the POST XHR is ignored.